# Irradiance sensor circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, light, photodiode

Im trying to measure the irradiance from the sun using the following TIA circuit:

[image]

I'm using a BPW34 photodiode due to the good spectral range and for being cheap.

Also the datasheet provides a graph of irradiance vs reverse light current, which I intend to use to obtain a Vout vs irradiance graph, due to the voltage produced in the output being linear to the current produced in the photodiode.

I'm feeding Vout to an microcontroller ADC and I'm obtaining decent results, depending how much light there is outside.

I understand the OPAMP basics, but after some research I saw the same configuration with a capacitor in parallel with R, the reason being to improve stability.

- Is the capacitor needed in this application?

Also any feedback to improve my circuit for this application would be helpful.

Comment: The BPW34 photodiode is a PIN. Memory serving, these are more important for high speed measurement situations. Are you sure you want to use that for irradiance? Also, measuring irradiance at ground level is a complex endeavor and involves multiple sensor types as well as full understanding of the behavior (thermal, drift over time, etc) of the sensors and methods for calibrating each of them.

Comment: Your schematic is of an ideal transimpedance amplifier circuit. But real circuits use real components that can have things like finite bandwidths, stability, saturation, etc, so additional components are required (sometimes a great very many depending on far you are pushing the envelope), but just for the basics, look at this PDF: https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu535/tidu535.pdf

Comment: Also, don't irradiance graphs require you wavelength selectivity? You will need filters if that's the case. Don't forget decoupling capacitors. You should be using C0G capacitors in the signal path, not more common types of capacitors due to temperature stability, piezoelectric and DC bias effects.

Comment: @jonk The goal is not to make something super accurate but rather something cheap that can easely relate irradiance to the power produced from a solar panel. I have seen some papers where they use just a single sensor (bpw34 or bpw21 or others) like this as a "low cost pyranometer".

Comment: @Toor that document is defenetly helpful. And yes, since the goal is measure the irradiance that hits a solar panel, which i think only obsorves wavelenghts from 380nm to 750 nm, ill need to filter mostly above 750 nm. But as i said, super accuracy is not really needed.